# VPN conflicts from using 2 VPNs

Tags: vpn, vpc, aws

My QA has a problem. They need to test the app, and the database at the same time. To access our app (testing environment), they need to connect to the company VPN through GlobalProtect, and then they have access. To access our database, they need to connect to DB through AWS VPN Client. However, having both connected at the same time on their local machines leads to unpredictable issues like timeouts and disconnections. How do I solve this?

Comment: You might want to consider using proper VPN routers instead of VPN software clients. Routers can be configured to run multiple connections simultaneously. Host configurations and issues are explicitly off topic here, so I'm afraid your question isn't valid here. You could try on [su] but I'm not sure if there's a solution unless you split the VPN clients to different (virtual) machines.

Comment: We're cursed with GP at work too - it should be configured to route for all IP ranges you need to access including the AWS addresses.  Multiple VPN clients will argue and you'll have a bad time, just like you are.